# Layout a Lightning Web Component Card as a standard related list

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

due to some business requirements, I need to develop a custom related-list for Contacts on the Account object. I wanted to do so with a LWC utilizing the lightning-card component.
Unfortunately, I am not able to format this component to look similar to a standard related list.
If you take a look at the screenshot, the grey background (like in Campaigns) and the border is missing.
[image]

Here is the code of the component:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Related Contacts" icon-name="standard:relationship" class="slds-card_boundary">
        <lightning-button label="New Contact" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="Add Relationship" slot="actions"></lightning-button>

        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="id"
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </p>
        <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Could you please help me with styling the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you don't have the background is that in SLDS Card header does not have the background:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/

The way Salesforce implements it is via Page Headers:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/

You will have remove the `title` & `icon-name` from `lightning-card` and implement your own `<div slot="title" class="slds-page-header">`. (do not include the `slds-card-header` as it has extra padding).

Btw: your example renders for me with border.

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: Just checked what classes are used in chrome dev console & checked what styles are defined for these classes :) Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, you can find a Custom Datatable which uses the described [SLDS Page Headers](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/) solution [here](https://github.com/svierk/awesome-lwc-collection/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/customDatatable). It uses a boolean property called "isUsedAsRelatedList" so that if present / set to true, the table is wrapped with the correct page header to fit into the related list layout using the correct styles like:

[image]